# How to manage imported certificates?

Tags: storage, certificates

I've got a X.509 certificate file (with a `.der` file extension) of a certificate authority that I want to trust (it's required to connect to my academic network). When I double-click on a `.der` file I can either import that certificate to the **Gnome2 Key Storage** or **User Key Storage** (by the way, what's the difference between those two?).

My question is, where these certificates are stored? I've check `/etc/ssl/certs` folder but I couldn't find the one that I've just imported. Also, how I can manage certificates after being imported (list them and remove)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the certificate in `/etc/ssl/certs/` manually. Additionally, you will want to add it to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` for applications that cannot deal with the directory format. For this, you first need to convert it from DER to PEM:

```
openssl x509 -in foo.der -inform der -out foo.pem
```

Then you install it into the system-wide certificate storage:

```
sudo openssl x509 -in foo.pem -out /etc/ssl/certs/$(openssl x509 -in foo.pem -noout -hash).0
sudo sh -c 'cat foo.pem >>/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually, I don't think it is an answer to my question. I know I can import certificates in a way that you've described, but I was wondering, what exactly happens to a `.der` certificate when trying to import it by a double click (GUI way). Especially, where it is stored.

Comment: Oh, okay. For that, you need to figure out which actual program is acting on the double click (this used to be the file manager of your desktop environment, but has become more complicated), and what actions it does (those days, this usually involves divining MIME types and looking through *.desktop files). Sorry, I'm a bit lost with today's GUIs.

Comment: Addition to the answer: The dedicated place for external certificates is `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` together with the command `update-ca-certificates`. Files in `/etc/ssl/certs` might be removed without notice on upgrades !